# TooltipHtmlUnsafe with content fetched from another div

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a tooltip with html content and the html I would like to be fetched from a children div which has angular markup in it.

Before I switched to ui-bootstrap I used the default bootstrap tooltip, which I created in a directive filling the content with `('.my-tooltip-content',element).html()`

Now with ui-bootstrap I tried using the same directive/logic on the ui-tooltip except that now I tried setting attribute variables. The problem is, that I don't know how to get the html from my `.my-tooltip-content` div rendered inside the tooltip, without loosing the bindings. If I use $interpolate, I get the html of my div properly rendered, but the output is fixed then of course (doesn't update anymore), $compile I have never used before, but I thought this would be the right place for such a use, maybe I don't know how to use it, but $compile gives me an exception about circular structure.

This is a shortened version of what my app looks like:
http://plnkr.co/edit/46NsEPArtm4hph0ROlPS?p=preview

Excerpt:

```
<div class="hover" tooltip-html-unsafe="" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom">
  <div>
      <p>Hover me {{booking.name}} !</p>
      <!-- about 20 more lines -->
  </div>
  <div class="my-tooltip-content"><!-- hidden by default -->
      <p class="booker-name">{{booking.name}}</p>
      <p>Does the name in this tooltip update?</p>
      <!-- about 10 more complex lines -->
  </div>
</div>

anApp.directive('hover', ['$compile','$interpolate', function($compile,$interpolate){
  return{
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      var html1,html2,html3;
      var content = $(element).find('.my-tooltip-content');

      // This works, but no binding
      html1 = $interpolate(content.html())(scope);

      // This I'd like to work, but I get "Can't interpolate: {{tt_content}} TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
      html2 = $compile(content.html())(scope);

      // This brings my html into the tooltip but curlybraces are curlybraces (not compiled)
      html3 = content.html();

      attrs.tooltipHtmlUnsafe = html1;
    }
  }  
}])
```

Is there an easy way to to get the html of `.my-tooltip-content` with all it's angular markup/bindings injected into the tooltip-content variable ?

PS: I know that I could squeeze all the html just directly into the tooltip-html-unsafe attribute, but I have so many lines in my real-world my-tooltip-content that this just wouldn't work (would make the tooltip-content html unreadable and unchangeable for humans).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use a child div, one solution use a function to pass the interpolated contents of the div to the tooltip.  For example:

```
anApp.directive('hover', ['$compile','$interpolate', function($compile,$interpolate){
  return{
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      scope.myTooltip = function() {
        var content = $(element).find('.tooltip-content');
        return $interpolate(content.html())(scope);
      };
    }
  }
}])
```

And your html would would need to be updated to use the new scope value for the tooltip:

```
<div class="hover" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{myTooltip()}}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom">
```

Here's the [updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2AkPWkx3y6tCqv06N0ya?p=preview)

Comment: it works and it's so easy, don't know why I didn't think of such a solution :o, thanks